# iOS toolbar appear fixed over UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a post detail page which displays the post and any comments, I'm trying to add a toolbar to the bottom of it with an input and a button that allows them to quickly add a comment.

I'm using [DAKeyboardControl](https://github.com/danielamitay/DAKeyboardControl) from cocoacontrols which has allowed me to add the toolbar how I want it and get it to display on the screen. The problem is it appears at the bottom of the tableView (Sometimes off screen) and I want it to display directly above the tab bar and be fixed there while a user scrolls through the tableView (as if the tableView is placed behind it)

I've included my code and any help is much appreciated.

```
UIToolbar *toolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f,
                                                                 self.view.bounds.size.height - 40.0f,
                                                                 self.view.bounds.size.width,
                                                                 40.0f)];
toolBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[self.view addSubview:toolBar];

UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f,
                                                                       6.0f,
                                                                       toolBar.bounds.size.width - 20.0f - 68.0f,
                                                                       30.0f)];
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textField.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
[toolBar addSubview:textField];

UIButton *sendButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
sendButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
[sendButton setTitle:@"Send" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
sendButton.frame = CGRectMake(toolBar.bounds.size.width - 68.0f,
                              6.0f,
                              58.0f,
                              29.0f);

[toolBar addSubview:sendButton];

self.view.keyboardTriggerOffset = toolBar.bounds.size.height;

[self.view addKeyboardPanningWithFrameBasedActionHandler:^(CGRect keyboardFrameInView, BOOL opening, BOOL closing) {
    /*
     Try not to call "self" inside this block (retain cycle).
     But if you do, make sure to remove DAKeyboardControl
     when you are done with the view controller by calling:
     [self.view removeKeyboardControl];
     */

    CGRect toolBarFrame = toolBar.frame;
    toolBarFrame.origin.y = MIN(keyboardFrameInView.origin.y, self.view.bounds.size.height) - toolBarFrame.size.height;
    toolBar.frame = toolBarFrame;

    //likely to lead to a retain cycle

    CGRect tableViewFrame = self.tableView.frame;
    tableViewFrame.size.height = toolBarFrame.origin.y;
    self.tableView.frame = tableViewFrame;
} constraintBasedActionHandler:nil];
```

Comment: If you are using a UItableViewController you will need to use a UIViewController instead

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why? Just so I can understand it properly.

Comment: sure are you using a `UITableViewController`? because they assume that the whole view is filled with the tableView, thus adding controll would just be on top. If you ever want to add any controls you will need to subclass the UIViewController instead